# How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer HAVING 32 BIT OS?

Tags: windows, memory

I want to replace the RAM within my computer to 4GB, it currently has 256mb of memory.

My question is what RAM is compatible with my motherboard?

Comment: whats the model name of your motherboard?

Answer (score -1):

Google your motherboard name (this is somewhere in your motherboard) and I'm sure you find out what ddr you have and how much memory it supports. There is no difference what OS you have (32/64bit).